# Mobile API design

Tags: json, api, design-patterns

We are designing API for a communication between a mobile application and server. We chose Json as a protocol. I just wonder about naming policy. Shall we have full names for properties or shortened names or just minimal codes?

1. measurementUnit, description
2. msrUnit, desc
3. mu, dsc

What are your best practices?

Answer (score 1):

The more descriptive you can make your properties the less likely you are to run into issues down the road with potential naming collisions and developer confusion.

This also comes in handy if you decide to make parts or all of your API public as it will be self-descriptive to your consumers.

The benefit gained from this will far out-weight the bandwidth costs of trying to shorten the names by a few characters here and there (unless you have MASSIVE payloads which you wouldn't want for a mobile app anyways).

Naming practice wise I'm a fan of camelCase, which you're already doing, and again providing descriptive property names.  But I've been working on putting together a collection of other best API design practices - hopefully they help - and feel free to reach out with any other questions:

http://blogs.mulesoft.org/api-best-practices-series-intro/

Thanks,
Mike